# Unity crashes on play setting up hand tracking (Oculus Quest)

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, virtual-reality, oculus, oculusquest

When trying to set up hand tracking following the hand tracking-documentation unity just shuts down when pressing play without any crashlog/warning. Here are the steps that I have done up until the crash to reproduce my problem:

1. Creating completely new scene.
2. Importing the Oculus Integration from asset store.
3. Switching platform to Android.
4. Add OVRCameraRig to hierachy.
5. Change OVRCameraRig's Hand tracking support to "Controllers & Hands" on OVR Manager-script.

Up to step 5 I can press play whenever and it starts as usual. But when doing the next step it crashes everytime.

6. Add "OVRHandPrefab" to OVRCameraRig > TrackingSpace > LeftHandAnchor/RightHandAnchor.

Has anyone experienced a similar problem to this?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: Unity does not crash when removing Link cable from laptop. So has certainly something to do with link.

Comment: What Unity version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried enabling hand tracking in your Quest Headset (while unplugged)?

Its in Settings -> Experiments -> Enable Hand Tracking

I also have 'Auto detect hands or controllers' enabled. To see your hands, the new OVRCustomHandPrefab does the trick.

[Edit]

Also the headset seems to cause crashes after its been sitting on the desk connected to Link for more than a few minutes. Unplugging and reconnecting will refresh it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you were able to solve this issue or not, but for any other person who is facing a similar issue, here is how I solved it:

1. When you add **OVRHandPrefab** to LeftHandAnchor and RightHandAnchor, set the gameobject to false in the inspector.
2. Then in your script, check if handtracking is enabled by running this code in Update() `OVRPlugin.GetHandTrackingEnabled()`
3. Set both the **OVRHandPrefab** to true only when `OVRPlugin.GetHandTrackingEnabled()` returns true, something like this:

   ```
   if (OVRPlugin.GetHandTrackingEnabled())
   {
       ovrHandPrefabLeft.SetActive(true);
       ovrHandPrefabRight.SetActive(true);
   }
   else
   {
       ovrHandPrefabLeft.SetActive(false);
       ovrHandPrefabRight.SetActive(false);
   }
   ```

This should avoid Unity from crashing.

Answer (score 0):

I wasnt getting crashes, but the hands seem to display on top of the controllers when switching so I added this script to the OVRCameraRig.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class CustomHandOverride : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject ovrHandPrefabLeft;
    public GameObject ovrHandPrefabRight;

    void Update()
    {
        if (OVRPlugin.GetHandTrackingEnabled())
        {
            ovrHandPrefabLeft.SetActive(true);
            ovrHandPrefabRight.SetActive(true);
        }
        else
        {
            ovrHandPrefabLeft.SetActive(false);
            ovrHandPrefabRight.SetActive(false);
        }
    }
}
```

Oculus Pro Unity 2023.3.1f1